# Best way to extract text from a Form with deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I have a form as an image below and I want to extract all information including printed text (book, ID) and number handwriting text ( number of orders) as a txt file. 
Does anyone can suggest me what is the best solution? 
My current idea is:

1. Using deep learning to get location of objects from each column.
2. Apply Tesseract to extract text from these objects. ( does any better lib?)
3. Using deep learning to reconize handwriting text

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a text localisation model called EAST to get extract text from a image.
https://github.com/argman/EAST

And then you can use one of those OCR models to transcribe the text.